# Where is Parallel Stacks in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

For [debugging Multithreaded Applications](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Debugging_Multithreaded_Applications.html), jetbrains mentioned using **Parallel Stacks**. Where can I find it in Android Studio? If not, is there a **plugin**?

Currently using Android Studio 4.2.1

Comment: Not really sure as I haven't touched Android in years, but maybe this helps? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/debug-coroutines-with-idea.html

Comment: yeah it's different from this ^ link. This is its definition from IntelliJ: "The Parallel Stacks pane lets you quickly observe all threads in your application and quickly navigate between them and their stack frames.". Also, it appears that IntelliJ has a UI feature that can be used for navigating between threads. But yeah, different from coroutines debugging.